# Remove id and rename action in urls in yii

Tags: php, url, yii, url-rewriting, yii-url-manager

Is it possible to remove id from url and rename action name?

For example if I write this:

```
'production' => 'products/index',
```

it works fine - in url I can see just "production", and is called  *'products/index'* page.

But if I write

```
'audits' => '/customPages/1',
```

Then it gives me

> The system is unable to find the requested action "1".

But as far as I understand this 1 is *id* , and its not an action, its a parameter in action.

How can I get '/customPages/1' page, but in url show something else?

Answer (score 0):

So why do not you just try this

```
'audits' => 'controller/action/id/1',
```

Suppose the **controller name is SITE and action is Target** so you can do this

```
'audits' => 'site/target/id/1',
```

Comment: I tried, but it got `Your request is invalid`. I can acsess this page via _customPages/view/1_, but when I write rule in urlManager `'audits' => '/customPages/view/1'`, i got this incorrect request.